# Showing real numbers with thousands separator while typing

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to develop a calculator app in Java. My problem is this:

When I type the digit 1 I see 1, But if I type 1.00 I only see 1.
I wish my user to see 1,234.00 if he types 1,234.00, and not just 1234.

Here's part of my code:

```
NumberFormat MyNumberForamt = new DecimalFormat("#,###.#####");
String finale = MyNumberForamt.format(Double.parseDouble(Ex1));
resultField.setText(finale);
```

What can I do?

Note: I am talking about showing the number as the user type it, not at the end of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you [read the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) for DecimalFormat?

```
....
0   Number  Yes Digit
#   Number  Yes Digit, zero shows as absent
....
```

Seems like you want to use the format:

```
new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
```

Comment: Then you need to word your question better, because this answer looks like exactly what you asked for.

Comment: I said...as I type. I need to show the decimal point during typing. It's a very clear question...